# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException selenium maven junit

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I'm new to Selenium, so I'm just trying to make simple test.
I'm getting an error when I try to put some code into this function.
This is the error I'm getting:

> exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class Selenium {
private static WebDriver browser; // I get error when I put this line

public static void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","webDriver/chromedriver904.exe");
    WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
    browser.get("http://weburl");
}
```

And the error shows on line WebElement:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Selenium");
    setup();
    WebElement pavadinimas = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form\"]/form/input[2]"));
```

Comment: You don't initialise the static field `browser`. You initialise a local variable called `browser`.

Comment: Remove the word `WebDriver` from `WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();`